# Iterate into structure

Tags: ruby

I have this Ruby code which I would like to optimize:

```
process_trx(['davivienda'], GATEWAY_NAME, base_params_for(:davivienda))
process_trx(['banco_de_chile'], GATEWAY_NAME, base_params_for(:banco_de_chile))
process_trx(['webpay'], GATEWAY_NAME, base_params_for(:webpay))
```

I tired this:

```
FIXED_BASE_PARAMS = %w(davivienda banco_de_chile webpay)

FIXED_BASE_PARAMS.each do |factory_data|
  process_trx(['#{factory_data.to_s.pluralize.humanize}'], GATEWAY_NAME, base_params_for(:#{factory_data.to_s.pluralize.humanize}))
end
```

What is the proper way to implement the code? I would like only to pass properly the names.

Comment: What's up with pluralize/humanize? Why did you add them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
%i(davivienda banco_de_chile webpay).each do |factory_name|
  process_trx([factory_name.to_s], GATEWAY_NAME, base_params_for(factory_name))
end
```

Comment: I get unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)

Comment: Fixed the closing parenthesis issue.

Comment: Why are you going the other way using `%i`? Using `%w` will be a minimum modification to the OP's original code.